# Symfony routing: how to redirect from UUID to custom slug

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have an entity that is reachable both using `http://example.com/company/d9c363ae-a1b7-11e6-a66d-9e9923e30d94/` and `http://example.com/company/custom-domain.com`.

Now, the `Company` can have a slug, but can also not have one.

So, I'd like to check if it has a domain set and if it has and if the URL is based on UUID, I want to redirect it to the version with the slug. If it hasn't a domain set, I simply show the page using the UUID.

I've done this following [this Symfony's tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html):

```
# routing.yml

redirect_company_to_domain:
    path: /company/{domain_host_or_id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Company:redirectToDomain }
    requirements:
        url: .*/$
    methods: [GET]
```

And in my controller I have write this method:

```
/**
 * Redirect the URLs with a trailing slash to the version without it.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function redirectToDomainAction(Company $company, Request $request)
{
    die(dump($company));
}
```

The problem is that the controller is never called.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Why the path is never intercepted by the route?

Maybe because I've mixed annotations and configuration in `routing.yml`? Because the routes of the `CompanyController` is all set using annotations.

But using `app/console debug:router` I can see correctly the route set:

```
redirect_company_to_domain             GET        ANY      ANY    /company/{domain_host_or_id}
```

Also, I'm sure the method described in the tutorial works as I've implemented it to remove trailing slashes.

I don't understand why it isn't working to make this redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because you've specified the parameter (in brackets) incorrectly.

Can you try this instead:

```
redirect_company_to_domain:
    path: /company/{domain_host_or_id}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Company:redirectToDomain }
    requirements:
        domain_host_or_id: .*/$
    methods: [GET]
```

I think that's the problem, but I'm not 100% certain. Can you try it out and let us know?